# Save and restore data in enyo

Tags: enyo

I am new to enyo. I want to save a state of variable (which is boolean) while app executes. Then exit the app. After that I want to get the state (true/false) of the variable when app re-opens. How to save and restore the data in enyo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use localStorage [(API Docs here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) to save your state every time the change in state occurs in your application:

```
myStateChange: function() {
    localStorage.myState = this.myState;
}
```

Note: to ensure that myStateChange is called every time you set it elsewhere, use this.set() method to set it, not this.myState = newValue;.

Then, in rendered() or create() method I would restore that state from localStorage.

```
rendered: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);           // Call base rendered method
    this.myState = localStorage.myState; // Restore your saved value from localStorage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no special hooks for data storage but it's very easy to tie into the native data storage options available for your platform.  You might take a look at these options:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/taking-your-web-apps-offline-web-storage-appcache-websql/

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

If you're using `enyo.Collection` you can get the records from it with `collection.raw()` and then use `JSON.stringify()` to get something you can put into localStorage.

You could even use cookies.  Hope that gives you some places to start looking from.